# Silverlight "Processing..." indicator

Tags: silverlight

I'm interested in including a "throbber" in my Silverlight application but since it is such a common thing I'd like to download one or follow some simple tutorial.  Can you suggest a site that can tutor me in this or that can just provide one for me to download?

By "throbber" I mean the thing that an app uses to show that it is processing. Sorta like the spinning blue Lifesaver in Windows 7 or the spinning beachball in OSX or any other of the million out there.

Also, to be clear, I'm not talking about altering the SilverLight app loading one.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [BusyIndicator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/realdevelopment/gg315125) control.

Comment: Agree that the BusyIndicator is the way forward and if interested I have a couple of blog entries. One on using the BusyIndicator with MVVM and having more than one in a view ( http://voiddog.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/silverlight-busy-indicators/) and a one with a couple of styles for the are a little simpler (http://voiddog.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/silverlight-busy-indicator-styles/)

Answer (score 0):

The Blacklight Busy Indicator (Loading Animation) looks really nice.(Download: http://blacklight.codeplex.com/ Example: [Interactive Controls - Loading Animation](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/)

Comment: the link didn't work as you originally posted it. Please check that my revision (which gets a web page and not a 404) goes to the page you intended.